# Find the invariant subspaces of the linear endomorphism of the coordinate space $F^n$ given by a Jordan block

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, invariant-subspace

I've achived to find invariant subspaces only once, but today I've got a problem to solve involving invariant spaces, and I'm not sure how to procedeed. Indeed I would like to find the invariant subspaces of the linear endomorphism of the coordinate space $F^n$ given by the following Jordan block:

$$\left(\begin{array}{ccccccc}
\lambda & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & \lambda & 1 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & \lambda & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & \lambda & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & \lambda 
\end{array}\right)$$

Could anyone explain to me a little bit how to invariant subspaces in this case ? Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: letting $M$ denote your matrix, and writing $T(x) = Mx$ (i.e., multiplying on the right by a column vector $x$), we see that

$$
\operatorname{span}(e_1)
$$
is invariant, because $T(e_1) = \lambda e_1 \in Span(e_1)$, where $e_1$ is the vector
$$
\pmatrix{
1\\0\\ \vdots\\0}.
$$

What about $\operatorname{span}(e_1, e_2)$?

Comment: Say me if it's wrong but we have in a same way we can see that for any u $\in {e_1,e_2,...,e_n}$ we have Tu = $\lambda u \in Span(e_1,e_2,...,e_n)$ so we can conclude that U = span {$e_i : i = 1,2,..,n$} is the invariant subspace ?

Comment: There are many invariant subspaces, not just one. For instance, if $M$ were the identity matrix, then **every** subspace would be invariant. The thing you've called $U$ is all of $\Bbb R^n$, and is an invariant subspace for any matrix transformation. The problem is to work out what the **others* are. (The trivial subspace $\{0\}$ is also invariant for every matrix transformation.)

Comment: Sorry for taking some time to answer, but the "other" invariant subspaces are actually the one I have no idea how to find, since I don't know luch about invariant subspaces. Is there a general method or an important info I'm missing ? Anyway thanks for your help so far @JohnHughes, I hope you can still help me